# echo data with text decoration

Tags: php, mysql, text-decorations

I want to display or echo my php mysql data with text decoration like underline or dotted line with css/html

Comment: What is your code so far? Where exactly is your problem?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, and please read the basics about HTML or CSS.

Answer (score 2):

```
<p style="text-decoration:underline;">
<?php echo $text ?>
</p>
```

anyway you can use css. If this not help, show me your sample code where u use echo.